# How can I delete a file or folder in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, directory, delete-file

How can I delete a file or folder in Python?

Answer (score 4858, accepted):

Use one of these methods:

- [`pathlib.Path.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) removes a file or symbolic link.
- [`pathlib.Path.rmdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rmdir) removes an empty directory.
- [`shutil.rmtree()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) deletes a directory and all its contents.

---

On Python 3.3 and below, you can use these methods instead of the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) ones:

- [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove) removes a file.
- [`os.unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink) removes a symbolic link.
- [`os.rmdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rmdir) removes an empty directory.

Comment: os.rmdir() on Windows also removes directory symbolic link even if the target dir isn't empty

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, `os.remove()` throws an exception, so it may be necessary to check `os.path.isfile()` first, or wrap in a `try`.

Comment: just for completion... the exception thrown by `os.remove()` if a file doesn't exist is `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Does `os.remove() ` take multiple arguments to delete multiple files, or do you call it each time for each file?

Comment: @Jérôme I think `missing_ok=True`, [added](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) in 3.8 solves that!

Comment: [os.removedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=removedirs#os.removedirs) removes a branch of empty directories (i.e. it first deletes empty leaf directory and then it continues up the branch hierarchy deleting all empty directories).

Comment: If you opened the file in a `with` statement and assigned it to `f`, you can issue `os.remove(f.name)` within the `with` block.

Comment: According to the Python documentation os.remove() and os.unlink() are synonymous and both can remove files and symbolic lins. Thats not exactly the same what you wrote? But I didn't try, maybe documentation is wrong?

Comment: This worked for me, but I noticed its a hard delete. I found send2trash library which creates a cross OS system to send to trash/recycling bin instead of permanently deleted in case anyone else was looking for that.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-delete-files-in-python-using-send2trash-module/

Answer (score 740):

### Python syntax to delete a file

```
import os
os.remove("/tmp/<file_name>.txt")
```

or

```
import os
os.unlink("/tmp/<file_name>.txt")
```

or

**[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) Library for Python version >= 3.4**

```
file_to_rem = pathlib.Path("/tmp/<file_name>.txt")
file_to_rem.unlink()
```

### Path.unlink(missing_ok=False)

Unlink method used to remove the file or the symbolik link.

> - If missing_ok is false (the default), FileNotFoundError is raised if    the path does not exist.
> - If missing_ok is true, FileNotFoundError exceptions will be ignored    (same behavior as the POSIX rm -f command).
> - Changed in version 3.8: The missing_ok parameter was added.

### Best practice

First, check if the file or folder exists and then delete it. You can achieve this in two ways:

1. `os.path.isfile("/path/to/file")`
2. Use `exception handling.`

**EXAMPLE** for `os.path.isfile`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

myfile = "/tmp/foo.txt"
# If file exists, delete it.
if os.path.isfile(myfile):
    os.remove(myfile)
else:
    # If it fails, inform the user.
    print("Error: %s file not found" % myfile)
```

#### Exception Handling

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

# Get input.
myfile = raw_input("Enter file name to delete: ")

# Try to delete the file.
try:
    os.remove(myfile)
except OSError as e:
    # If it fails, inform the user.
    print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
```

#### Respective output

```
Enter file name to delete : demo.txt
Error: demo.txt - No such file or directory.

Enter file name to delete : rrr.txt
Error: rrr.txt - Operation not permitted.

Enter file name to delete : foo.txt
```

#### Python syntax to delete a folder

```
shutil.rmtree()
```

Example for `shutil.rmtree()`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import shutil

# Get directory name
mydir = raw_input("Enter directory name: ")

# Try to remove the tree; if it fails, throw an error using try...except.
try:
    shutil.rmtree(mydir)
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
```

Comment: Exception handling is recommended over checking because the file could be removed or changed between the two lines (TOCTOU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)  See Python FAQ https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: Also [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) is preferred over [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-lbyl) in Python.

Comment: what's the point to catch the exception in the very last example ?

Answer (score 126):

Use

```
shutil.rmtree(path[, ignore_errors[, onerror]])
```

(See complete documentation on [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)) and/or

```
os.remove
```

and

```
os.rmdir
```

(Complete documentation on [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove).)

Comment: Please add the pathlib interface (new since Python 3.4) to your list.

Answer (score 99):

Here is a robust function that uses both `os.remove` and `shutil.rmtree`:

```
def remove(path):
    """ param <path> could either be relative or absolute. """
    if os.path.isfile(path) or os.path.islink(path):
        os.remove(path)  # remove the file
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)  # remove dir and all contains
    else:
        raise ValueError("file {} is not a file or dir.".format(path))
```

Comment: I.e. 8 lines of code to simulate the ISO C `remove(path);` call.

Comment: @Kaz agreed annoying, but does remove deal with trees? :-)

Comment: `os.path.islink(file_path):`  a bug, should be `os.path.islink(path):`

Comment: Robust, well, it does not handle patterns, like "*.bak"...

Comment: Why not use `glob`: `for p in glob.glob(path)`

Answer (score 54):

## Deleting a file or folder in Python

**There are multiple ways to Delete a File in Python but the best ways are the following:**

1. **os.remove()** removes a file.
2. **os.unlink()** removes a file. it is a Unix name of remove() method.
3. **shutil.rmtree()** deletes a directory and all its contents.
4. **pathlib.Path.unlink()** deletes a single file The pathlib module is available in Python 3.4 and above.

## os.remove()

### Example 1: Basic Example to Remove a File Using os.remove() Method.

```
import os
os.remove("test_file.txt")
print("File removed successfully")
```

### Example 2: Checking if File Exists using os.path.isfile and Deleting it With os.remove

```
import os
#checking if file exist or not
if(os.path.isfile("test.txt")):
    #os.remove() function to remove the file
    os.remove("test.txt")
    #Printing the confirmation message of deletion
    print("File Deleted successfully")
else:
print("File does not exist")
#Showing the message instead of throwig an error
```

### Example 3: Python Program to Delete all files with a specific extension

```
import os 
from os import listdir
my_path = 'C:\\Python Pool\\Test'
for file_name in listdir(my_path):
    if file_name.endswith('.txt'):
        os.remove(my_path + file_name)
```

### Example 4: Python Program to Delete All Files Inside a Folder

To delete all files inside a particular directory, you simply have to use the * symbol as the pattern string.
#Importing os and glob modules
import os, glob
#Loop Through the folder projects all files and deleting them one by one
for file in glob.glob("pythonpool/*"):
os.remove(file)
print("Deleted " + str(file))

## os.unlink()

os.unlink() is an alias or another name of os.remove() . As in the Unix OS remove is also known as unlink.
Note: All the functionalities and syntax is the same of os.unlink() and os.remove(). Both of them are used to delete the Python file path.
Both are methods in the os module in Python’s standard libraries which performs the deletion function.

## shutil.rmtree()

### Example 1: Python Program to Delete a File Using shutil.rmtree()

```
import shutil 
import os 
# location 
location = "E:/Projects/PythonPool/"
# directory 
dir = "Test"
# path 
path = os.path.join(location, dir) 
# removing directory 
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

### Example 2: Python Program to Delete a File Using shutil.rmtree()

```
import shutil 
import os 
location = "E:/Projects/PythonPool/"
dir = "Test"    
path = os.path.join(location, dir) 
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

## pathlib.Path.rmdir() to remove Empty Directory

Pathlib module provides different ways to interact with your files. Rmdir is one of the path functions which allows you to delete an empty folder. Firstly, you need to select the Path() for the directory, and then calling rmdir() method will check the folder size. If it’s empty, it’ll delete it.

This is a good way to deleting empty folders without any fear of losing actual data.

```
from pathlib import Path
q = Path('foldername')
q.rmdir()
```

Answer (score 49):

You can use the built-in [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module (requires Python 3.4+, but there are backports for older versions on PyPI: [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/), [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)).

To remove a file there is the [`unlink`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) method:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(name_of_file)
path.unlink()
```

Or the [`rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rmdir) method to remove an **empty** folder:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(name_of_folder)
path.rmdir()
```

Comment: What about a non-empty directory though?

Comment: @Pranasas Unfortunately it seems there is nothing (natively) in `pathlib` that can handle deleting non-empty directories. However you could use [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree). It has been mentioned in several of the other answers so I haven't included it.

Answer (score 43):

> ### How do I delete a file or folder in Python?

For Python 3, to remove the file and directory individually, use the [`unlink`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) and [`rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rmdir) `Path` object methods respectively:

```
from pathlib import Path
dir_path = Path.home() / 'directory' 
file_path = dir_path / 'file'

file_path.unlink() # remove file

dir_path.rmdir()   # remove directory
```

Note that you can also use relative paths with `Path` objects, and you can check your current working directory with `Path.cwd`.

For removing individual files and directories in Python 2, see the section so labeled below.

To remove a directory with contents, use [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree), and note that this is available in Python 2 and 3:

```
from shutil import rmtree

rmtree(dir_path)
```

### Demonstration

New in Python 3.4 is the `Path` object.

Let's use one to create a directory and file to demonstrate usage. Note that we use the `/` to join the parts of the path, this works around issues between operating systems and issues from using backslashes on Windows (where you'd need to either double up your backslashes like `\\` or use raw strings, like `r"foo\bar"`):

```
from pathlib import Path

# .home() is new in 3.5, otherwise use os.path.expanduser('~')
directory_path = Path.home() / 'directory'
directory_path.mkdir()

file_path = directory_path / 'file'
file_path.touch()
```

and now:

```
>>> file_path.is_file()
True
```

Now let's delete them. First the file:

```
>>> file_path.unlink()     # remove file
>>> file_path.is_file()
False
>>> file_path.exists()
False
```

We can use globbing to remove multiple files - first let's create a few files for this:

```
>>> (directory_path / 'foo.my').touch()
>>> (directory_path / 'bar.my').touch()
```

Then just iterate over the glob pattern:

```
>>> for each_file_path in directory_path.glob('*.my'):
...     print(f'removing {each_file_path}')
...     each_file_path.unlink()
... 
removing ~/directory/foo.my
removing ~/directory/bar.my
```

Now, demonstrating removing the directory:

```
>>> directory_path.rmdir() # remove directory
>>> directory_path.is_dir()
False
>>> directory_path.exists()
False
```

What if we want to remove a directory  and everything in it? 
For this use-case, use `shutil.rmtree`

Let's recreate our directory and file:

```
file_path.parent.mkdir()
file_path.touch()
```

and note that `rmdir` fails unless it's empty, which is why rmtree is so convenient:

```
>>> directory_path.rmdir()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1270, in rmdir
    self._accessor.rmdir(self)
  File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/username/directory'
```

Now, import rmtree and pass the directory to the funtion:

```
from shutil import rmtree
rmtree(directory_path)      # remove everything
```

and we can see the whole thing has been removed:

```
>>> directory_path.exists()
False
```

### Python 2

If you're on Python 2, there's a [backport of the pathlib module called pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/), which can be installed with pip:

```
$ pip install pathlib2
```

And then you can alias the library to `pathlib`

```
import pathlib2 as pathlib
```

Or just directly import the `Path` object (as demonstrated here):

```
from pathlib2 import Path
```

If that's too much, you can remove files with [`os.remove` or `os.unlink`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove)

```
from os import unlink, remove
from os.path import join, expanduser

remove(join(expanduser('~'), 'directory/file'))
```

or

```
unlink(join(expanduser('~'), 'directory/file'))
```

and you can remove directories with [`os.rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rmdir):

```
from os import rmdir

rmdir(join(expanduser('~'), 'directory'))
```

Note that there is also a [`os.removedirs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.removedirs) - it only removes empty directories recursively, but it may suit your use-case.

Comment: `rmtree(directory_path)` works in python 3.6.6 but not in python 3.5.2 - you need `rmtree(str(directory_path)))` there.

Answer (score 11):

This is my function for deleting dirs. The "path" requires the full pathname.

```
import os

def rm_dir(path):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(cwd, path)):
        return False
    os.chdir(os.path.join(cwd, path))

    for file in os.listdir():
        print("file = " + file)
        os.remove(file)
    print(cwd)
    os.chdir(cwd)
    os.rmdir(os.path.join(cwd, path))
```

Answer (score 10):

shutil.rmtree is the asynchronous function, 
so if you want to check when it complete, you can use while...loop

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.rmtree(path)

while os.path.exists(path):
  pass

print('done')
```

Comment: `shutil.rmtree` is not supposed to be asynchronous. However, it may appear to be on Windows with virus scanners interfering.

Comment: @mhsmith *Virus scanners*? Is that wild speculation, or do you actually know that they can cause this effect? How on earth does that work if so?

Answer (score 8):

```
import os

folder = '/Path/to/yourDir/'
fileList = os.listdir(folder)

for f in fileList:
    filePath = folder + '/'+f

    if os.path.isfile(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)

    elif os.path.isdir(filePath):
        newFileList = os.listdir(filePath)
        for f1 in newFileList:
            insideFilePath = filePath + '/' + f1

            if os.path.isfile(insideFilePath):
                os.remove(insideFilePath)
```

Comment: This will delete only the files inside the folder and subfolders leaving the folder structure intact..

Answer (score 6):

### For deleting files:

```
os.unlink(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

or

```
os.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

Both functions are semantically same. This functions removes (deletes) the file path. If path is not a file and it is directory, then exception is raised.

### For deleting folders:

```
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
```

or

```
os.rmdir(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

In order to remove whole directory trees, `shutil.rmtree()` can be used. `os.rmdir` only works when the directory is empty and exists.

### For deleting folders recursively towards parent:

```
os.removedirs(name)
```

It remove every empty parent directory with self until parent which has some content

> ex. os.removedirs('abc/xyz/pqr') will remove the directories by order 'abc/xyz/pqr', 'abc/xyz' and 'abc' if they are empty.

For more info check official doc: [`os.unlink`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.unlink) , [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove), [`os.rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rmdir) , [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree), [`os.removedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.removedirs)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) issue highlighted by [Éric Araujo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder#comment99147016_42641792), you can catch an exception to call the correct method:

```
def remove_file_or_dir(path: str) -> None:
    """ Remove a file or directory """
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(path)
    except NotADirectoryError:
        os.remove(path)
```

Since `shutil.rmtree()` will only remove directories and `os.remove()` or `os.unlink()` will only remove files.

Comment: `shutil.rmtree()` removes not only the directory but also its content.

Comment: State of Python skills at SO: Had to scroll all the way to here to find the first solution without the race.

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference is to work with pathlib objects - it offers a more pythonic and less error-prone way to interact with the filesystem, especially if You develop cross-platform code.

In that case, You might use pathlib3x - it offers a backport of the latest (at the date of writing this answer Python 3.10.a0) Python pathlib for Python 3.6 or newer, and a few additional functions like "copy", "copy2", "copytree", "rmtree" etc ...

It also wraps `shutil.rmtree`:

```
$> python -m pip install pathlib3x
$> python
>>> import pathlib3x as pathlib

# delete a directory tree
>>> my_dir_to_delete=pathlib.Path('c:/temp/some_dir')
>>> my_dir_to_delete.rmtree(ignore_errors=True)

# delete a file
>>> my_file_to_delete=pathlib.Path('c:/temp/some_file.txt')
>>> my_file_to_delete.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

you can find it on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To remove all files in folder

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/to/folder/*'))
files = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/to/folder/*.csv')) // It will give all csv files in folder
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

To remove all folders in a directory

```
from shutil import rmtree
import os

// os.path.join()  # current working directory.

for dirct in os.listdir(os.path.join('path/to/folder')):
    rmtree(os.path.join('path/to/folder',dirct))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

def del_dir(rootdir):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in filenames: os.remove(rootdir+'/'+filename)
        for dirname in dirnames: del_dir(rootdir+'/'+dirname)
    os.rmdir(rootdir)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple and effective way to remove all files and directories using List Comprehension.

```py
 import glob
 from os import path, remove, rmdir
 
 #The directory you wish to empty...
 your_dir = "/path/to/dir/with/contents"
 # Use list comprehension to ensure we don't compromise on speed
 [            
    remove(f) if path.isfile(f)
    else [remove(ff) for ff in glob.glob(path.join(f, "*"))] + [rmdir(f)]
    for f in glob.glob(path.join(your_dir, "*"))
 ]
```

This is what it works:

1. We first use glob to get all files and directories in the directory you want to empty. In this case, "your_dir" `for f in glob.glob(path.join(your_dir, "*"))`
2. Then we remove any files within this "parent directory" `remove(f) if path.isfile(f)`
3. This line `else [remove(ff) for ff in glob.glob(path.join(f, "*"))] + [rmdir(f)]` is the most interesting.

- First, because these will be directories we empty them using the `glob` and `remove` combination `[remove(ff) for ff in glob.glob(path.join(f, "*"))]`
- Now that the "child directory" is empty, we need `rmdir` to remove it. To do so, we use a hack; **list concatenation**. By adding `+ [rmdir(f)]` we force python to evaluate `rmdir(f)` and thus remove the directory for us. Viola!

Answer (score 1):

My prefered method ***os.walk*** and ***os.remove*** with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

To delete **all files** in **one** directory:

```
import os
from os import walk

path1 = './mypath1/'

[os.remove(path1+ff) for ff in next(walk(path1), (None, None, []))[2]]
```

If you have **various directories** you want to delete **all files**:

```
import os
from os import walk

path1 = "./mypath1/"
path2 = "./mypath2/"
path3 = "./mypath3/"

for p in [path1,path2,path3]:
    [os.remove(p+ff) for ff in next(walk(p), (None, None, []))[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Move file or directory under a temp directory and delete it. This will be also atomic

```
import os
import pathlib
import tempfile


def rm(path: str):
    """Remove file or directory"""
    _path = pathlib.Path(path).expanduser()
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=_path.parent) as _dir:
        _path.replace(os.path.join(_dir, _path.name))
```