# Download files modified after given time with sftp in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

I am writing a bash script that will get files from one directory of remote host.
Here, I want to get files that were modified after given time.

```
sftp userme@remote_host_addr:/somedirectoryonremoteserver
> mget
```

Here, how can I pass the timing to `sftp` command to get only files whose modified time is greater than given time.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather difficult to implement this using the OpenSSH `sftp` client.

You would have to:

- list the directory using `ls -l` command;
- parse the results (in shell or other script) to find names and times;
- filter the files you want;
- generate another `sftp` script to download (`get`) the files you found.

---

A way easier and more reliable would be to give up on the command-line `sftp`. Instead, use your favorite scripting language (Python, Perl, PHP) and its native SFTP implementation.

For an example, see:
[Download files from SFTP server that are older than 5 days using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56287892/850848)

---

Or use a more capable SFTP client.

Comment: I achieved it using rsync (only modified files will copy) since it was difficult to implement using sftp