# How to delete file uploaded to sever after processing it in Django?

Tags: django, file

What I am trying to do is that when I upload an audio file which needs to be processed it gets stored in the server, but that file is not needed anymore after user leaves the website. How should I efficiently manage this in Django? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the file after processing?

```
import os
os.remove(path_to_file)
```

Comment: Thanks. Even I thought of doing so but I thought to confirm if any other solution exists. Anyways I will use os.remove() .

Comment: Django is just Python :) See also this post about that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-do-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python