# os.remove claims a file is "busy" for a while

Tags: python

I'm processing a file and then want to remove it. My code ends with:

```
...
tar.extractall(dir=...)
tar.close()
os.remove(filename)
```

This sometimes causes an error:

```
[Errno 16] Resource busy: 'skyimage/sgptsiskyimageC1.a1.20160415.000000.jpg.tar'
```

I was able to work around this by telling Python to keep trying until it works:

```
while True:
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
        break
    except OSError as err:
        continue
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: This question may actually be a duplicate.  There is a ton of discussion on this topic and related points at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder  Have a look at that stuff and learn more than you ever thought possible on removing files and folders and directories in Python.

Comment: is that some special filesystem? like dropbox or other?

Comment: You didn't show the whole code. Maybe you opened the file before but didn't close it?

Comment: Your code is reasonable but I would add a short sleep and consider a timeout and error path if the problem doesn't resolve in a reasonable amount of time.