# How to delete a folder by if function?

Tags: python

I am having 100 sub-folders in a folder. Some of the sub-folder is having following count result(`ls 24*.pdf | wc`) as one (1). How can i delete the sub-folders (1) by python. I think that I can use if function. If the count is 1, delete the folder. How?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module to remove the directory and `glob` to get the files that match your query like:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("mydir/24*.pdf")
```

Then get the count with:

```
file_count = len(files)
```

Then check if it's > 1, remove it with `os.rmdir()`.

```
import os
if file_count > 1:
    os.rmdir("mydir")
```

You can get the file list using `os.listdir('mydir')`, but you'd have to filter the filenames manually.