# How to delete temp folder data using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I create python script to delete data in temp folder in windows environment system.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)

Answer (score 1):

you can go like this

```
import os
os.remove("C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.*")
os.remove("C:\Windows\Temp\*.*")
os.remove("C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items*.*")
```

Comment: how can i automate this it should run daily at specified time

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script/

Comment: but the code u specified giving error at  os.remove("C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.*") itself

Comment: hey I'm Linux user, you should add the correct  path for target folders. Linux file system is so far different from window, so i can't help in what is actual path of them, hope it's not a big deal to you.