# Deleting Temp folder in Windows, TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, python-os

I'm trying to delete the `Temp` folder in Windows with python script but get this error:

```
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

This is my script:

```
is_admin = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
if is_admin==False:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", message="You need to run this program as "
                                          "administrator to cleanup your pc!")
else:
    user=(os.path.expanduser("~"))
    tmp_folder=(user+"/AppData/Local/Temp")
    listdir=os.listdir()
    path=os.path.join(tmp_folder, listdir)
    os.remove(path)
```

What is my mistake here?

Comment: `listdir()` returns a list, whereas `join()` wants two strings

Comment: but is there a way to delete all files inside a folder?

Comment: or all files that you "can" delete beacuse few are used currently?

Comment: One way is to combine a for loop with your list and delete one by one. There might also be a function in `os` for deleting entire folders. You'll have to look it up.

Comment: you can't delete the Temp folder completly on windows because there are every time used some files. But how can I make this loop?
edit: sorry, i'm a python noob :/

Comment: You can iterate through files in the folder and attempt to delete each one, but do that between a pair of `try` / `except` statements. This will allow you to ignore errors that occur when an attempt is made to delete something that's in-use or otherwise non-deleteable.

Comment: and after except i write "pass"?

Comment: you mean something like that:
...`else:
        user=(os.path.expanduser("~"))
        tmp_folder=(user+"/AppData/Local/Temp")
        
        for file in os.scandir(tmp_folder):
            try:
                os.unlink(file.path)
            except:
                pass`
sorry, stackoverflow dessert the code kinda

Comment: Yes, essentially, but I would suggest putting a specific type of exception, such as `except PermissionError:` or `except OSError:` on the `except` statement — whichever one occurs when you don't use the `try` & `except`. Doing so is better than a bare `except` which can hide unrelated problems with your code (like `SyntaxError`) that you wouldn't want ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As it says, `os.path.join()` takes string arguments, but you're passing it a list. You are also, from the looks of it, trying to remove a folder with `os.remove` but that can only be used for individual files.

Try something like this for your `else` block instead:

```
user = os.path.expanduser("~")
tmp_folder = os.path.join(user, "/AppData/Local/Temp")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tmp_folder, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except OSError:
            print(f"Could not delete the file at {file}")
```

This makes use of `os.walk()` to go through the files in the directory and delete them individually. Let me know if this works for you and does what you want it to.

Comment: Sorry I'm on Linux so I can't test deleting the temp folder, there may be some restrictions on that but I can write a for loop to delete individual files if this doesn't work

Comment: first at all thank you for trying to help me but it didn't work.

Comment: beacuse rmtree is deleting the folder, but it have to delete all files one by one :/

Comment: and if it can't delete a single file, it have to pass this file

Comment: I found a solution at this site. The same should work with other folder too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795746/how-to-delete-temp-folder-data-using-python-script

Comment: I tried changing to deleting individual files, does it do what you want to now? Sorry I still can't test it so just let me know and I can change it

Comment: thank you very much but i found this command for windows command line to delete all files inside a folder, that you can delete, because maybe in the temp folder are files still used.
`del /q/f/s %TEMP%\*`

Comment: @Rolv: `os.walk` normally traverses the directory tree by walking it top-down, but I think you would want to do it bottom-up when deleting files (which it supports, but it's not the default).