# Is their any path file method to delete itself if its a file?

Tags: python, cmd

do Path-file objects have any method to delete itself if its a file?
can we use **os.remove**?
method **.rmdir()** can't be used when correspond to file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996603/1531971 If there is some specific API you are referring to, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the path is file or directory with:

```
os.path.isfile("asd.txt")
os.path.isdir("asd")
```

And you can delete it with:

```
os.remove() will remove a file.

os.rmdir() will remove an empty directory.

shutil.rmtree() will delete a directory and all its contents.
```