# Delete Zipped Folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unzip

I'm literally new to python and trying to learn stuff. I have a python script that basically unzips from a compressed zipped folder from source and extracts all to the destination folder. Added I also wanted to delete the source contents  once it is extracted. How would I achieve this ? thanks for help in advance!

Basically,inside this path "**L:\Python\Source Zipped files**" I have multiple zipped folders. My query, unzips each folder and extracts to the final destination. I'm looking for an approach, like first when it unzips the first folder, and extracts and then it should be deleted from the source folder. Included a snippet of how the source folder looks like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh0Ei.png)

Here is my query

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
import json

data_dir = r'L:\Python\Source Zipped files'
temp_dir =  r'L:\Python\temp1'
new_dir = r'L:\Python\temp2'
final_dir = r'L:\Python\Destination Unzipped files'

big_list = os.listdir(data_dir)

archive_count = 0
file_count = 152865
basename1 = os.path.join(final_dir,'GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT')
basename2 = os.path.join(final_dir,'XACTDOC')

my_time()
archive_count = len(big_list)
logging.info('Unzipping {} archives...'.format(archive_count))
for folder in big_list:
    prior_count = file_count
    logging.info('Starting: {}'.format(folder))

    try:
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        pass
    os.mkdir(temp_dir)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(data_dir,folder),mode='r') as a_zip:
        a_zip.extractall(path = temp_dir)
        archive_count += 1
        logging.info('Cumulative total of {} archive(s) unzipped'.format(archive_count))
        bigger_list = os.listdir(temp_dir)
        logging.info('Current archive contains {} subfolders'.format(len(bigger_list)))
        for sub_folder in bigger_list:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(temp_dir,sub_folder),mode='r') as b_zip:
                b_zip.extractall(path = new_dir)
            file1 = "%s (%d).%s" % (basename1, file_count, 'xml')
            file2 = "%s (%d).%s" % (basename2, file_count, 'xml')
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(new_dir, 'GENERIC_ROUGHDRAFT.xml'), file1)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(new_dir, 'XACTDOC.xml'), file2)
            file_count += 1
        logging.info('{} subfolders unzipped'.format(file_count - prior_count))
    
    my_time()
logging.info('Total of {0} files -- {1} pairs -- should be in {2}'.format(2*(file_count-1), file_count-1, final_dir))

time.sleep(1)

my_time()
```

Comment: Are you asking on how to delete a file?

Comment: delete the contents of zipped folder and the folder itself once unzipped and extracted

Comment: And you've searched yourself and most likely gotten to this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder

Comment: I tried this shutil.rmtree(), but it delete the actual folder itself, which I dont want. I tried os.remove(), where i get Permission denied error. I wanted to delete only the contents within "Source Zipped files" folder that has unzipped and extracted

Comment: I am also a bit confused... So you want this deleted `os.path.join(data_dir,folder)` from `data_dir`, which is just a regular directory? Or is any of that not so? What would that be? And you've tried `os.remove(os.path.join(data_dir,folder))` and got `OSError` hinting permission denied? Could it not be taken for the face value  that user running the script cannot unlink the file in question? Or, but I am guessing as I am not really a Windows person, so not sure what exactly would be the exception raised, the file has RO attribute set?