# Work with list variable in python 3 and delete folders based on it

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Sorry if I named it wrong, this is my first try in python make some working script. I made list with `Dictionary Cursor`, but I need now to work with is as variables and delete folders. For example.

If I will found in `/data/system/domain.tld` and `domain.tld` is listed in from my select in ["name"] I want to delete that directory. How should I proceed with my code when I want this functionality?

```
import pymysql.cursors
import os
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='password',
                             db='database',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql="SELECT id, name, state FROM domain WHERE state='2'"
cursor.execute(sql)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total number of records for deleting is: ", cursor.rowcount)

print("\nPrinting each domain record")
for row in records:
    print (row)
    print("id = ", row["id"], )
    print("name = ", row["name"])
    print("state  = ", row["state"], "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the above syntax is working correctly, i.e. producing rows where the `row[name]` values are the paths of the directories you wish to delete, then you should just need to add the delete command to your `for` loop as a new line.

[Delete a file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/delete-a-file-or-folder)

The above link has a lot more information on how to delete files and folders using Python. Looking at the top answer, the `shutil.rmtree()` function looks like it should delete a directory based on a given path.

[You can find the shutil documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

So, if you wanted to continue to print all those variables, your `for` loop should just need the additional line with the `shutil.rmtree()` function:

```
for row in records:
    print (row)
    print("id = ", row["id"], )
    print("name = ", row["name"])
    print("state  = ", row["state"], "\n")
    shutil.rmtree(row["name"])
```