# Why does my code delete everything in the folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I wrote code to detect all the .exe files in a directory but instead it deletes everything in the folder. How can I change the code to make it delete only the .exe files?

```
import os
import shutil

dir_name = "/Users/plapl/Downloads/"
source = os.listdir("/Users/plapl/Downloads/")

for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".exe"):
        shutil.rmtree(dir_name, files)
```

Comment: Because `rmtree` deletes a directory and all it's contents. Did you mean to use `remove()`Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996628/1935238) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only delete directories with `shutil.rmtree` but not files (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).

You should use `pathlib` or `os` instead.

```
os.remove(f'{dir_name}/{files}')

pathlib.Path(f'{dir_name}/{files}').unlink()
```

Answer (score 2):

`shutil.rmtree` removes the *entire directory* specified by its first argument. The second argument to `shutil.rmtree` is `ignore_errors`, telling the function whether to ignore errors that occur. It is not a file to remove.

`shutil.rmtree` is a completely inappropriate tool for the job you want to do. You need something like [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove).