# Delete a specific folder with a path as a parameter in python

Tags: python, sys, shutil, rmdir

I want to delete a Folder named "testfolder" and all the subfolders and files in it. I want to give the "testfolder" path as a parameter when calling the python file. For example ...... (testfolder location) and there it should delete the "testfolder" when the folder exists

Comment: *If* this is the only requirement of the Python file, why not just use the shell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shutil.rmtree() for removing folders and argparse to get parameters.

```
import shutil
import argparse
import os

def remove_folder(folder_path='./testfolder/'):
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
        print(f'{folder_path} and its subfolders are removed succesfully.')
    else:
        print(f'There is no such folder like {folder_path}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Folder Remover')
     parser.add_argument('--remove', '-r', metavar='path', required=True)

     args = parser.parse_args()

     if args.remove:
         remove_folder(args.remove)
```

You can save above script as 'remove.py' and call it from command prompt like:

```
  python remove.py --remove "testfolder"
```

Comment: is it possible to give the path where the testfolder is as a paramter when calling the script? So it should be python remove.py --remove ..\..\.. and there it should delete the folder testfolder?

Comment: If you meant to ask that: if you use  python remove.py --remove "your_folder_path" or shortly  python remove.py -r "your_folder_path"  you can easily remove the folder and its subfolders.

Comment: is it also possible that i can give the folder path as a parameter but not the name of the folder so i can delete more folder like this. remove.py -r "your_folder_path and then there on this path it will delete al folder which are in the code e.g testfolder and testfolder2? How can i do that

Comment: you can loop your args.remove like that:    if args.remove:
    for arg in args.remove.split(" "):
         remove_folder(args)
and after that you can call python remove.py -r "testfolder testfolder2"

Answer (score 2):

I guess this might be what you're looking for

```
import os
import shutil

pathLocation = # Whatever your path location is
if os.path.exists(pathLocation):
     shutil.rmtree(pathLocation)
else:
    print('the path doesn\'t exist')
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer @Gad. The path should not be in the file only the target folder name. The path where the targetfolder is should be set as a paramter when calling the python file, so i can use this programm for every path

Comment: @noggy You can upvote Gad's answer and mark it as accepted after a few minutes have passed.  That's the best way to make folks coming here know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use absolute path and import only the rmtree function from shutil import rmtree as this is a large package the above line will only import the required function.

```
from shutil import rmtree
rmtree('directory-absolute-path')
```