# Delete file in local machine after success upload via sftp

Tags: python

Im newbie in python
currently I was successfuly upload file via sftp using paramiko.
but I want to delete that file in my local machine after upload process end successfully.
Anyone can help ?
below my script for upload file

```
import paramiko
import os
import glob
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='domain.com',username='root',password='root')
ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put('C:/testfile.txt','./testfile.txt')
ftp_client.close()
```

I don't know how to delete after upload has been success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: I mean in my case I uploading big file. How i know when my upload file has been success then I will delete that file in my local machine.

Comment: So your actual question isn't how to delete a file, it's how to know if uploading is done. If file deletion has nothing to do with your question, then don't mention it, since it's obviously confusing everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.remove("file.csv")
```

Comment: But how about if my file around up to 50 mb, how can i know if upload process end successfully before i delete that file ?

Comment: you can use try catch to handle exceptions of your code