# How to store image file or file temporary using python or django rest_framework without saving in the database? I am new to Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

How to store image file or file temporary using python or django rest_framework without saving in the database?

In dajngo rest_framework I did these things in a function based view.

```
temp_file = request.FILES['document_file']
```

Then, how I store this file temporary without saving in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below function which handles a .txt file.You can create a `temporary_folder` directory. To write file to `temporary_folder`:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('/full/path/to/temporary_folder/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Once your business logic is done, you can delete the file. Please check this [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)

Other Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: After this, how can I use this file for further works. As a example to ectract data from the file and store them into a database using camelot, when this file is a PDF file.