# Saving to Parquet throws an error in Dask.dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

When performing the operation: `Dask.dataframe.to_parquet(data)`, if `data` was read via `Dask` with a given number of partitions, and you try to save it in parquet format after having removed some columns, it fails with e.g. the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: part.0.parquet'
```

Anyone encountered the same issue?

Here is a minimal example - note that way 1 works as expected, while way 2 does NOT:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

# -------------
# way 1 - works
# -------------
print('way 1 - start')
A = np.random.rand(200,300)
cols = np.arange(0, A.shape[1])
cols = [str(col) for col in cols]
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=cols)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=11)

# compute and resave
ddf.drop(cols[0:11], axis=1)
dd.to_parquet(
    ddf, 'error.parquet', engine='auto', compression='default',
    write_index=True, overwrite=True, append=False)
print('way 1 - end')

# ----------------------
# way 2 - does NOT work 
# ----------------------
print('way 2 - start')
ddf = dd.read_parquet('error.parquet')

# compute and resave
ddf.drop(cols[0:11], axis=1)
dd.to_parquet(
    ddf, 'error.parquet', engine='auto', compression='default',
    write_index=True, overwrite=True, append=False)
print('way 2 - end')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, great, you've spotted a bug due to `overwrite=True` option. So what happens is when `overwrite=True` option is set, dask removes the path, see [these lines](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/f41325512a4251dbaa7f7c781414d913066a6c34/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py#L512-L532). Now, in your example `ddf` is lazy, so when it's time to write the data, dask tries to read the files, but they are already gone by now.

So one work-around solution is to save the new dataframe into a different path, then remove the old folder and move the new dataframe's folder to the old folder (some of the options are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)).

Another option is to load the `ddf` in memory (if it fits) and then use your code:

```py
print('way 2 - start')
ddf = dd.read_parquet('error.parquet')

# # compute and persist in memory (note do not use
# # .compute because the dataframe will turn into
# # pandas data frame
ddf = ddf.drop(cols[0:11], axis=1)
ddf = ddf.persist()
dd.to_parquet(
    ddf, 'error.parquet', engine='auto', compression='default',
    write_index=True, overwrite=True, append=False)
# print('way 2 - end')
```

As a side note, when you run `ddf.drop(cols[0:11], axis=1)`, if you want this to be changed in the dataframe, you will need to assign it:

```py
ddf = ddf.drop(cols[0:11], axis=1)
```

update: there is some relevant discussion [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7466)

Comment: Thank you @SultanOrazbayev, I modified the question and added a minimal example

Comment: Thank you, @SultanOrazbayev, that is what I was looking for! And yes, it seems like a bug to me.