# Is there a way to delete all the contents of a folder, without deleting the folder?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried to use `shutil`, but rather than deleting the contents of the folder it just deletes the whole folder.

```
def delete_song():
    print("Deleting song")
    shutil.rmtree('./song_downloads')
    print("Deleted song")
```

However it didn't print out "Deleted song". I also tried to use os.remove()

```
def delete_song():
    print("Deleting song")
    for file in os.listdir('./song_downloads'):
        os.remove(file)
        print("Deleted file")
```

But this didn't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: Check output of os.listdir. It lists only names of files, whilst you need absolute or relative path to file to work with `os.remove`. Probably doing `os.remove(os.path.join('./song_downloads', file)` will solve your issue.

Comment: @nngeek I don't think so, these are the solutions I had tried already unfortunately. I have no idea why my loop will not delete all of the files in ./song_downloads, and that seems to be the only solution that will not delete the folder.

Comment: @Grysik I do get the error `Failed with: The system cannot find the file specified` when I use the os.remove() method. However the print statement says the exact file name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment from @grysik on your question, the output of `os.listdir()` only gives unqualified file names (e.g. no path), therefore the call to `os.remove()` won't be able to find the file in the current working directory, so you need to pass the path in as well.

The below will do what you require:

```
def delete_song(directory):
print("Deleting song...")
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    qualified_file=os.path.join(directory, f)
    os.remove(qualified_file)
    print(f"Deleted file [{qualified_file}]")
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `pathlib` which allows you to work with the entire Path of the file so you can remove it, and print out the qualified file name.

from pathlib import Path

```
def delete_song(dir : str) -> None:        
    for file in Path(dir).glob('*'):
        print(f'Removing song --> {file.stem}')
        file.unlink()
    print('Songs deleted.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove files in a directory, you can try this -

```
from pathlib import Path

[f.unlink() for f in Path("/path/to/folder").glob("*") if f.is_file()]
```