# How to delete folder with python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, temp

I want to delete a folder inside the Windows drive **'C'**

but i get **PermissionError**

I used the 'os' module as usual but I do not know exactly how to solve the **access** problem

**Code:**

```py
import os
os.remove("C:\\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp")
```

**Error:**

```
line 2, in <module>
   os.remove("C:\\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp")
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
```

Comment: I think ```AppData``` is protected by windows. It is always ```hidden``` until you manually reveal it

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder

Comment: Is the real path **exactly** as posted here? Cause you have: *"C:\\Users **\n** ame\AppData\Local\Temp"*. Double the backslashes (although in the exception text they are *OK*). What does *os.path.isdir* indicate for that folder? **Is the user *name* same user that runs the script**?

Comment: So, after all, it is a *dupe* of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder. Unfortunately, I can't mark the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete a folder in Python you can use os.rmdir but only **for empty directories**

For non-empty ones you can use shutil.rmtree, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(folder_name)
```

This deletes the folder, even if it contains files.