# (Python) Delete file after send to API

Tags: python, delete-file

I just got to know the world of programming and python was the first thing I learned.. This program already can extract data from .txt file and send it to API..
But the things is I don't know how to delete the file,after the data have been extracted and send to the API... Here is my coding...

```
from fileinput import close
import os
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import glob
import time

'''List'''
data_send_list = []

'''Path'''
path = "./file"

'''File List'''
file_name = []

URL = 'http://.......'

def main():
    
    #Main
    print("Main Def" "\n")

    #ScanFile
    data_send_list = scan_files(path)
    
    #send_API
    for json in data_send_list:
        send_api(URL, json)

def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open (file_path, 'r') as file:
        data_dictionary={}
        data = file.readlines()

        ...............

        '''UPDATE THE DICTIONARY'''
        data_dictionary.update([(...)(...)])

        return data_dictionary

def scan_files(path):
    list = []

    os.chdir(path)
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        list.append(read_text_file(file))
        
    return list

def send_api(url,json,):

    requests_session = requests.session()

    post_api = requests_session.post(url,data=json)
    print("Sending API")

    if(post_api.status_code >= 200 and post_api.status_code <300):
        print("Successful. Status code: ",post_api.status_code)
        print("\n")
#i hope that i can delete the file here

    else:
        print("Failed to send to API. Status code: ",post_api.status_code)
        print("\n")
        close()

    return post_api.status_code
```

I was hoping that if the data can be sent to API... and give output "status code: 200" the data file will be deleted... while the data that is not sent, the file will remain

Comment: Using `os.remove` you may remove the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a file or folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-do-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

There would be a lot of better ways other than my answer.

```py
import os

...

def send_api(url,json,path):  # You need to add function parameter path to use at this function

    requests_session = requests.session()

    post_api = requests_session.post(url,data=json)
    print("Sending API")

    if(post_api.status_code >= 200 and post_api.status_code <300):
        print("Successful. Status code: ",post_api.status_code)
        print("\n")
        os.remove(path)  # use os.remove function to remove file

    else:
        print("Failed to send to API. Status code: ",post_api.status_code)
        print("\n")
        close()

    return post_api.status_code
```