# Deleting files from folder

Tags: python

I have files in folder with names 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg ... etc.
And I have list of names 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg
How can I delete files in folder according to names from this list?

import os
import glob

> fileList = glob.glob('/home/varung/Documents/python/logs/**/*.txt',
> recursive=True)
>
> for filePath in fileList:
> try:
> os.remove(filePath)
> except OSError:
> print("Error while deleting file")

I don't understand why quotes don't work.
I found this code but it only works for patterns. I can't understand how to put names from list inside. I need to delete files in folder if their names match names from list.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. do you want to delete files which their name is included in a list, or is close to an item and/or matches a pattern? also, do you want to scan subdirectories as well, or the root directory alone?

Comment: Please include some code to let us know what you've tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a file or folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-do-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python)

Comment: [edit] your question to add code. It is unreadable as a comment

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code and clarification there, then delete the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code does what you've described:

```py
import os

removals = ['a.txt', 'b.jpg']

for object in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(object) and object in removals:
        os.remove(object)
```

Comment: Looks good and logical but it doesn't work. File is still in folder.