# Delete files from workspace databricks with Python

Tags: python, databricks, delete-file

I have a group of files in the Workspace of DataBricks that I would like to delete in group.  I am using this Python script:

```
from pyspark.sql import *  #not sure if it is necesary to delete the files
dbutils.fs.rm('/Workspace/Users/xxx@company.com/*.json', True)
```

The answer I get is `False` below the Notebook and it doesn't delete any file.

Is there something wrong with my script?

Comment: I think using wildcards like that doesn't work for dbutils.fs.rm. You might want to use a %sh cell and just ```rm``` (And no, you don't need the import)

Answer (score 1):

`dbutils.fs` is for interacting with dbfs, not workspace.

You can use [python file i/o](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996628/496289) if you want to [interact with workspace](https://dpe-aws.docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace-interact.html).

So in your case it would be:

```
from pathlib import Path

for f in list(Path('/Workspace/Users/xxx@company.com/').glob('*.json')):
    Path.unlink(f)

# Older python version
import os, glob
for f in glob.glob('/Workspace/Users/xxx@company.com/*.json'):
    os.remove(f)
```